# How does "Valar Dohaeris" serve as the response to "Valar Morghulis"?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

"All men must die" signifies the inevitability of death, and "All men must serve" signifies that we all need to perform our roles in the world.

In this case, *why* is "Valar Dohaeris" the traditional answer? How does "Valar Dohaeris" fit as the response to "Valar Morghulis"?

Is there an implicit ".. but first.." between the sayings? Or is it purely tradition at this point with no real explanation?

Comment: I think it's tradition, a ritual answer. I can't find any references for this, though. [The Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Valar_morghulis#cite_note-Raffc22.7B.7B.7B3.7D.7D.7D-1) cites Chapter 22 of *A Feast for Crows* as a reference, but I don't have it handy to check.

Comment: @AndresF. I found a explanation of valar dohaeris, but it doesn't reference valar morghulis. Ch 22 of AFFC: "Then stay . . . but remember, the House of Black and White is not a home for orphans. All men must serve beneath this roof. Valar dohaeris is how we say it here." I'm assuming that's what the Wiki is referencing

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe your interpretation of "Valar Dohaeris" is incorrect.  This greeting/response belongs to a culture that worships the many-faced god, i.e. the god of death.

My assumption is that "all men must serve" does not refer to performing one's role in the world; rather, it refers to death as an inevitable act of service to the many-faced god.

The address "Valar Morghulis" and response "Valar Dohaeris" are simultaneously a greeting and a religious ritual.

Comment: But those who serve R'Hlor (I don't think I spelled that correctly) also use it. Both Mellisandre and Thoros of Mir use it so it's not exclusive to those who serve the Many Faced God.

Comment: But has either of them ever responded to "Valar Morghulis" with "Valar Dohaeris?"

Comment: I can't remember if they do in any of the books so maybe not. I know for sure they do when they meet each other at the camp of the Brothers Without Banners on the show. Of course the show doesn't follow the same continuity as the books so your theory could still stand.

Comment: ...Also,  their usage of the expression could be formal rather than religious. Plenty of people use expressions like "Oh Jesus," "I swear to God," and "Bless you" without belonging to any religion at all.  High Valyrian to them might be what French was to many European aristocrats.

Comment: Except that while Thoros isn't all that pious, the Red Lady definitely is. It would seem out of character for her to invoke any other religion than the lord of light, regardless of if its an expression or not. Sort of like how some people don't put the word "god" in front of "dammit" because it's considered rude and or "taking the lords name in vain"

Comment: Sure, but it seems like "all men must serve" could still apply. It may mean the many-faced god in its original intent, but there is nothing offensive about it to someone who has her own god in mind. Besides, language is rarely rigid. The most pious of priests would call Thursday "Thursday," even though it originally refers to Thor.

Comment: With regards to your answer, that makes sense for when the worshipers of the Many-Faced God use it, they themselves will eventually die but first they will serve him in bringing His gift of death. Where it gets weird in my opinion is when the non-worshipers use the phrase. In that case it almost seems "meaningless". The people using it aren't serving the Many-Faced God, and even the ones that *do* kill people, wouldn't be following the rules the faceless men follow (which I assume are akin to the 10 commandments for the followers of the Many-Faced God)..so do they not know what they're saying?

Comment: @chriszumberge: I think the idea is that *everyone* serves the many-faced god because everyone dies.  Death is a service to him, and, eventually, "every man serves."  Valar Morghulis - Valar Dohaeris.  But as for some people using it without knowing its meaning, that isn't exactly strange.  When you say "Bye" to someone, do you necessarily mean "God be with you?"  That's where "goodbye" game from.  High Valyrian expressions have its origins, but that doesn't mean they retain their meaning to everyone who speaks it.

Comment: @MishaRosnach well put, I think with that final comment I'd consider this a wholly satisfactory answer.

Comment: @MishaRosnach: Death is the gift of the many-faced-god, not a service to him. Serving the many faced god is guiding others towards receiving this gift, let it be consoling, consulting or delivering.

Comment: @user1129682: It's common for religions to conflate "service"  and "gift" (most Christians consider prayer both service and gift, for instance). I am not sure why you think that only guiding others towards death qualifies as service to the many-faced god. Real-life religions have priests, imams, and rabbis, but the idea of serving God is virtually never restricted to their work.

Comment: @MishaRosnach: Service is where I'm heading off to shortly. We will pray there and I have heard of many gifts, but service was never one of them. There is a noticable distinction between gift and service. We receive or at least perceive gifts, while we perform service. While they often occur together, quid pro quo, only in the rarest cases one is the other. I also never said "only". Yet, guiding people towards death in every conceivable way is certainly the most prominent work of the "monks" in the House of the Black and White.

Comment: @user1129682: My comment referred to a general trend among different religions (including many Christian denominations). I am always happy to hear different people's personal takes on their own religion - but, barring chat, SF/Fantasy stack exchange might not be the best venue for that. I suggest that we agree to disagree.

Comment: @MishaRosnach: Can you at least point me to some external source explaining how gift and service are often the same in "real-life" religions? I strongly disagree with that assessment. It does not concur with anything I have seen or heard of before. In ASOIAF it is very clear that those you serve the many faced god give the gift, which is death, which is not a service.

Comment: @user1129682: I entered "the gift of prayer" into Google, and clicked on the very first link: https://www.lds.org/general-conference/2007/04/using-the-supernal-gift-of-prayer?lang=eng You may personally disagree with the idea of service to God and gift from God being the same, but I assure you that many people have that belief; it is not an esoteric idea in the slightest, and a religious community unfamiliar with the idea is a rather unusual one.  As for ASOIAF - I too think it's clear, and we nevertheless disagree on it.

Comment: @Monty129 In TV series, there seems to be confusion between R'llor and Many-faced-god as per the [notes](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/R%27hllor#Notes) given on wikia.com

Comment: Do you have exact quotes from the stories which support your interpretation?

Comment: @RichS No - to my knowledge, there are no exact quotes explaining the exchange. But I think the story provides enough information. The only "service" the Many Faced God seems to care about has to do with providing death. We also know that the MFG doesn't seem to approve of reckless murder, and each death needs its own covenant - so all men must serve isn't likely to mean murder. However, everyone provides the MFG with at least one death - by dying. And, since all men must serve is a direct response to all men must die, I think we can make a fairly educated guess.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the premise of the accepted answer.

> My assumption is that "all men must serve" does not refer to performing one's role in the world; rather, it refers to death as an inevitable act of service to the many-faced god.

If that were the case, then the greeting and the response would be redundant. I believe *all men must serve* implies that everyone must serve their purpose in life before death.

Comment: Religious rituals tend to have a great deal of redundancy. Greetings too are often redundant. For instance, the response to "As-Salaam-Alaikum" is "Wa-Alaikum-Salaam" - almost the same thing, grammatically changed mainly to offset the redundancy of the exchange. And the standard response to "How do you do" is "How do you do." But even so, I don't think it's redundant in this case. "Valar Morghulis" describes reality, and "Valar Dohaeris" qualifies it. Without the response, the greeting is just a obvious fact; without the greeting, the response is meaningless.

Comment: The first gift was given to a slave in the mines of Valeria. IIRC even the first few gift_s_. "All men must serve" might be a reference back to the origin of the religion of the many faced god. As such it could intent to remind people that death must not be a bad thing. Or, it could mean that everybody is worthy of receiving the gift. With these meanings the response would identify oneself as peer to the greeter, or recognise the greeter as a peer. Reminding people they are all the same before their god.

Comment: Do you have exact quotes from the stories which support your interpretation?

Comment: It seems to me it's a pair of statements about what the speakers believe to be the nature of existence -- a serious version, with spiritual undertones, of the old joke, "Nothing in life is certain but death and taxes."

Answer (score 0):

Valor Morghulis is a greeting. But VM plus an assassin's coin gives the speaker *great power*, as per Joaquin when giving the coin to Arya. But what is this compelling power of the phrase and coin?. The power is in the *response* Valar Dohaeris. All men must serve. The power is that the responder will now *actually* provide some service, either to the Many Faced God, or to the bearer of the coin. The compulsion is so strong as to compel service without even taking the coin or payment. So Valar Dohaeris is not a dusty old empty set of words, but a compulsion to provide such service that all men must provide. Especially in the presence of the assassin's coin.

Answer (score -1):

My impression is that all men must die and all men must serve are the SOIAF equivalent of how we say ‘Only two things in life are certain: death and taxes.’
In their world, taxes are replaced with the will of the gods. Thus you say (this is certain:) All men must die. And my reply is (this also is certain:) all men must serve (the gods).
Another analogy might be greeting someone with, ‘what do you know?’ I know we all die, they might reply. ‘And we all pay the gods in the form of service...’ chortles, chortles.

Comment: Hi. Do you have any source for this theory of yours?

Answer (score -2):

> All men must die

⇒ Since we all finally die and seeing how shallow are our daily worries, how vain and futile is our existence comparing to greater achievement, there must be something better to do.

⇒ Besides, Multiface God belong to something beyond our understanding.

⇒ Since he lives in such complex world, he must know what to do in every basic life as we have.

> All men must serve

---

This reasoning is done in a lot of religions (if not all).

Comment: I believe the spoiler block is not entirely necessary. The quote is already mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: @Stark07 I must admit it was only to raise the suspense.